# In Chai assertion library what is the use of "assert.equal()" when we already have "assert.deepEqual()" and "assert.strictEqual()"?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

In **Chai assertion library** what is the use of "**assert.equal()**" when we already have "**assert.deepEqual()**" and "**assert.strictEqual()**" for both strict and deep equality assertions?
Also it is mentioned that "assert.equal()" uses non-strict equality. What is the difference between non-strict and deep equality?
Why can't we just use "deepEqual" instead of "equal"?

Answer (score 4):

When you check out the [Chai documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) for the `.deep` functions, you'll get a pretty clear description:

> Causes all .equal, .include, .members, .keys, and .property assertions
> that follow in the chain to use deep equality instead of strict (===)
> equality.

When you use `equal`, Chai uses a `===` comparision. So when comparing objects, Chai will check for **reference**.

When you use `deepEqual`, Chai will go down the object hierarchy and compare every **value** of every property.

Example:

```
const a = {"a": "a"};
const b = {"a": "a"};
expect(a).to.equal(b); // false, as a refers to a different object than b
expect(a).to.deep.equal(b); // true, as the value of every property of a and b equals
```

Comment: I have mentioned about the chai "assert" and not "expect"..... For 'expect' we just have "equal" and "deepEqual" and that is perfectly fine. But for "assert" in Chai we have "equal", "strictEqual", and "deepEqual".

Answer (score 0):

https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/

Javascript as 3 comparisons mainly ,

== , === and Object.is(obj1,obj2)

> - double equals ( `==` ) will perform a type conversion when comparing two things, and will handle `NaN` , `-0` , and `+0` specially to conform to IEEE 754 (so `NaN != NaN` , and `-0 == +0` );
> - triple equals ( `===` ) will do the same comparison as double equals (including the special handling for `NaN` , `-0` , and `+0` ) but without type conversion; if the types differ, `false` is returned.
> - `Object.is` does no type conversion and no special handling for `NaN` , `-0` , and `+0` (giving it the same behavior as `===` except on those special numeric values).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#a_model_for_understanding_equality_comparisons

But all these comparisons works only on primitive values (non objects like : **string, number, bigint, boolean, undefined, symbol, and null** .)

For Object , it will consider the reference also , meaning it will check whether the objects have same reference or not else it will equate to false.  Hence we cannot use any of the three methods for comparing Objects

assert.equal does '=='
assert.strict does '==='
assert.deep recursively check key, value and members instead of reference (so deep content validation)